# On Mac, Audio output is not working, Not a simple problem

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio, macos-ventura

So its already been months. this glitch stays for 20-30 days and then disappears automatically and suddenly it appears one day.

I spoke with Apple care genius and in the name of troubleshooting they wiped my Drive, re-installed the OS and still the problem persist(No diagnostic problems detected) and since I am aware that the problem is a temporary software bug. I decided not to send the laptop to the apple hardware inspection and get it checked which was going to cost me $700 to $1400.

So I am extending my request to this forum and asking for help.

**Problem:** No audio output when connected to In-built speaker output profile.

**Symptoms:**

1. Youtube video is stuck in first frame.Timeline continues to play.
2. Quick time player opens but doesn't play video, stuck in the first frame.
3. No Audio output in any browser.
4. But if I switch to 'Serato Virtual Audio' sound output, YT video play(Not stuck in the first frame anymore), timeline is playing, but no audio output.
5. If the audio output is changed to an external output speaker or earbuds. Everything is normal; means YT works in all browser and the audio output works fine. BAU. [image]

Since MAC OS is linux based. What can I do to make my sound output work. Is there anything that I can check using terminal that would. help solve this problem?(I am just throwing some ideas!)

Any help will be appreciated! Thank for reading!

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming and probably belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com